# How to pass a top-level object to a low-level one?

Tags: software-design

What I mean by top-level is an object which is created in one of the top layers of the program (for example the main function). A low-level object is created far deep in the other objects' code.

So let's say my main function looks like this :

```
public static void Main(String[] args) 
{
    SomeClass topLevelObject = ...
    SomeOtherClass otherTopLevelObject = ...
}
```

Now, let's say that `otherTopLevelObject` creates an object, which itself creates another object, and so on to an object that we'll call `lowLevelObject`

Then what if `lowLevelObject` needs `topLevelObject` ? What is a good way to tackle this ? Does `topLevelObject` simply needs to be passed along the constructor tree ? Or maybe it is best to avoid completely such cases. If so, how do I avoid them ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't want to create a dependency in `lowLevelObject` on `topLevelObject`.  For example, if `lowLevelObject` is a thing that saves data to disk, and `topLevelObject` is the current state of a game, you probably don't want `lowLevelObject` to have to know how to interpret the state of the game.  Instead, you should have `topLevelObject` be able to implement some interface or method such as `Serialize`, then all `lowLevelObject` needs to do is know how to handle serialized data.

That way, when you create a new `SomeOtherClass2` that implements crash logging, you don't need to modify `lowLevelObject` to now know how to interpret crash data.  Just implement `Serialize` for `SomeOtherClass2`, which `lowLevelObject` already knows how to deal with.

Comment: Maybe I need to be a little more specific. I have a first object which is a Java swing window; the low level object here is a widget inside the window. The trick is, the window itself, and many of its members, need a specific second object.
Anyway thanks for the insight